# Updating a published LiveCard causes an InstanceCountViolation

Tags: java, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a LiveCard with a layout set up using RemoteViews:

```
mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.dashboard_card);
mLiveCard.setViews(mRemoteViews);
...
mLiveCard.publish(LiveCard.PublishMode.REVEAL);
```

After publishing the Card I create an AsyncTask which is supposed to load some data and then update the Card by calling this method:

```
private void updateViews() {
    mRemoteViews.setString(R.id.topQuestion, "setText", "some text");
    mLiveCard.setViews(mRemoteViews);
}
```

Running this code causes the following error:

```
android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.google.glass.home.voice.TouchMainMenuActivity; instances=3; limit 1
at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

As far as I know I followed the instructions in the official guides but I can't find a way to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm getting these a lot too, and I'm not sure why.